# why Jenkins 1.598 and tomcat 8 auto deployment does not work

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I have Jenkins 1.598. I install auto deployment plugin into jenkins (But it is not for tomcat 8, there is no update yet).

Everything worked fine! After build finished, it starts redeployment. But sometimes I have such error, and I do not understand when and why it happens. When I restart tomcat, everything goes again fine!

```
  Deploying C:\jenkins\test\target\tr-gui.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
      Redeploying [C:\jenkins\test\target\tr-gui.war]
      Undeploying [C:\jenkins\test\target\tr-gui.war]
    ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
    org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to undeploy [C:\jenkins\test\target\tr-gui.war]
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.undeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:140)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:178)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:981)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:959)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1784)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
    Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\servers\tomcat 8\webapps\test]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.

        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:480)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.undeploy(TomcatManager.java:420)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.performUndeploy(Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.java:62)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.undeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:130)
        ... 17 more
    org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\servers\tomcat 8\webapps\tr-gui]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.

        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:480)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.undeploy(TomcatManager.java:420)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.performUndeploy(Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.java:62)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.undeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:178)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:981)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:959)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1784)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model

.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Sending e-mails to:  test@mytest.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that at the time your test and tr-gui apps were not closed properly.

Here's an old comment by  Matt Mello (from [this bug report](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10320)):

> I had the same problem.
>
> It turns out that we had a log4j appender setup in our app to append
>   to an HTML file in our webapp's directory, and apparently log4j would
>   not release the file until we properly shutdown the appenders.
>   Shutting down the app wasn't enough. This might have been due to the
>   fact that log4j itself is loaded from tomcat instead of from the app?
>   Not sure.
>
> Anyway, I added code in the servlet destroy method to cleanup the
>   appenders and this ensured that the file was closed so that tomcat
>   could delete the directory.
>
> [Don't even get me started on the security issues involved in what we
>   were doing. That is another topic.]
>
> Note that velocity might also write some logs into your webapp's
>   directory. I believe I have seen that before, too.